# Get numbers from a cell in a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is a table in which there is a column with lines of the approximate form:

`NAME:ENTRY ID:1562.003:NAME:Defenses:Command::::NAME::ENTRY ID:1574.006:NAME:Execution:Dynamic::::TAXONOMY NAME:ATTACK:ENTRY ID:1574.007:`

The number of characters can be different.

I want to take only numbers from each line, I use the code:

```
import csv
with open("/root/test.csv", encoding='utf-8') as r_file:
    file_reader = csv.reader(r_file, delimiter=";")
    count = 0
    for row in file_reader:
        n = f'{row[1]}'
        print(''.join([x for x in n if x.isdigit()]))
```

unfortunately, my code only leads to the result:

`156200315740061574007`

I wanted to get the result in the form of:

`1562.003; 1574.006; 1574.007`

Could you please tell me how to implement such a conclusion?
Thank you very much

Comment: Well your print statement , your telling it to just join them up with nothing seperating.  do print(";".join... ) or some thing. Your still not catching the decimals though. Could maybe try x.isnumber (or is.float) in your lamda function instead. Is what I would try first off..

Comment: It's unclear what the "lines of the approximate form" *are*. Please [edit] your question and show several input lines and the output you want from them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to test whether the cells contain what appears to be a number. For efficiency, you can then compile that regular expression before starting the loop.

The expression is a bit verbose unfortunately, but it is looking for something that contains an optional decimal point (maximum of one), and which must also contain at least one digit somewhere, but if there is a decimal point then there only needs to be at least one digit  on one or other side of it.  It is also allowed to have a leading minus sign, and maybe some whitespace at the start and end.

```
import csv
import re

is_number = re.compile(r"^\s*-?(\d+\.?\d*|\d*\.?\d+)\s*$").match

with open("test.csv", encoding='utf-8') as r_file:
    file_reader = csv.reader(r_file, delimiter=":")    
    for row in file_reader:
        print('; '.join(cell for cell in row if is_number(cell)))
```

NB your delimiter for the input seemed to be wrong - I changed it to `:`.

Comment: I wanted to clarify one point, but what if I still want to apply this solution only to a specific column? for example `n = f'{row[1]}'` at the same time, `delimiter=` must have `,`, I tried to do this: `n.split(':')` but it didn't work out.

Comment: @AlexRebell you have the list `row` - if you only want certain columns you could always make a slice, maybe even with only a single element e.g. use `row[2:3]` in place of `row` for just the third column. (This would maybe not be how I would have written it just in order to process one column, but it is the minimum change to the existing answer.)